# What's the odt file and why its content wasn't updated when using lettre package

Tags: pdftex, lettre

I have a letter document that I have written on 23/12/2013. Today I have copied the directory that contains the `tex` file along all the other files generated after compilation. I have changed the `tex` file and I have noticed that LaTex keep the original date (23/12/2013) even though I have used the command `\today`.

When I looked to log file I found that LaTeX read the date from the `odt` file and the contents of this file wasn't updated with the correct date.

```
\expandafter\def\csname origdate1\endcsname{le 23/12/2013}
```

I have also this warning:

```
Package lettre Warning: Mode `origdate'.
```

What's the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  If `origdate` option is selected, *and* the file `.odt` exists, `lettre` uses the date from this file.    Otherwise it stores the current date there.

Presumably this is useful if you want to retypeset the letter at a later date, but to preserve the original date.

If you do not need the feature, just delete `.odt` file or the option `origdate`.

Comment: Thanks I copied the template from Internet and I didn't know the option does.